# How to Bind Dataset Result to ASPX page using Eval() function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code that retrieve total no of questions, answers and points from database using stored procedure. And the method returns DataSet. In ASPX page I have used Repeater and in that I have placed controls such as labels. So now how to bind the value to the labels.

---

Below is the code of stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_GetUserStat
    @RegId int
AS
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS question FROM tblQuestion WHERE RegID=@RegId ;
    SELECT COUNT(*)  AS answer FROM tblAnswer WHERE RegID=@RegId;
    SELECT Points FROM tblPoints WHERE RegID=@RegId ;
RETURN 0
```

---

Below is the C# code

```
public DataSet GetUserStat(LogicLayer li)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetUserStat", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegId", li.RegId);
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds, "UserStat");
            return ds;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

---

Below is the code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         LogicLayer li = new LogicLayer();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
            li.RegId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["RegId"]);
            rptUserStat.DataSource = li.Get_UserStat(li);
            rptUserStat.DataBind();


        }
    }
```

---

Below is the ASPX code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptUserStat" runat="server" > 
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <div class="ul_list ul_list-icon-ok"> 
      <ul> 
        <li>
          <i class="icon-question-sign"></i>
          <a href="user_questions.html">Questions<span> ( <span><%#Eval("") %></span> ) </span></a>
        </li> 
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please share you aspx too.

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="rptUserStat" runat="server" >
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                             <div class="ul_list ul_list-icon-ok">
          <ul>
           <li><i class="icon-question-sign"></i><a href="user_questions.html">Questions<span> ( <span><%#Eval("") %></span> ) </span></a></li>                                                                                           </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater?

Comment: Always add important information like code or other clarifications into the question and do not leave them as comments. I have removed the unnecessary heading-like formatting also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

akash.

you can do like these, it's not a proper code but will help you.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptUserStat" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Questions</th>
            <th>answer </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# Eval("")%></td>
        <td><%# Eval("")%></td>            
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

or you can use Container.DataItem like below,

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptUserStat" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Questions</th>
            <th>answer </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem , "question")%></td>
        <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Answer")%></td>            
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: But how to access values from dataset as the code returns dataset and  stored procedure returns question and answer as variables with values. So how to bind it and which variable to use........in Container.DataItem("")...?

Comment: it is throwing error..An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'answer'.

Comment: i have a meeting so i cannot give you full code, but i will clear a flow, first you need to make a proeprty class, for answer and question, now from code behind you have to fill these class, it might be List<string> where you have to store value you have grabed from your stored procedure.

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx

Comment: Thanks baka I got it

Comment: but only one variable is binded other two of them throwing same error as above

Comment: ok, now update your question with one variable code, maybe there is some minor mistake..

Comment: as you suggested that databinder.eval(...) only question variable is binded other two of them ie answer and point is not binded. but Dataset is returned then it should contain the value...But I am using eval instead of Databinder.Eval(...)

Comment: Code: <%#Eval("question")==null?"0":Eval("question") %>                                                                                                                    <%#Eval("answer")==null?"0":Eval("answer") %> and same for point

Comment: hi akash, http://code.runnable.com/UjMj269qAWwQAAB3/asp-net-how-to-use-repeater these will explain everything i suggested you...